# Binary Data in sqlite database versus Image in Applications Folder or Storing images from internet

Tags: xcode, core-data, uiimage, nsdata, binary-data

I was just thinking what is the best way to keep images in IPhone/iPad (XCODE) application if I'm getting them from internet dynamically. My main concern is if I'm storing it in my database as Binary data, will it decrease my efficiency when creating the queries to database?

In that case is it better to store them in Application's folder?

Thanks for responds.

Comment: why don't you do both, **measure** and decide based on factual evidence instead of internet speculation, only you know your usage heuristics.

Comment: I actually did both in previous projects, but it had limited amount of images, this time client might have 20000 images. So I need to know if someone already did that. I can't feed 20000 images to my app now.

Comment: what makes you think someone else's 20K images will be the same average size as your 20K images? If you can't mock up a service to create and populate your app with 20K images something is wrong.

Comment: Jarrod, have you done something similar before? If yes please tell me if you stored in databse as binary data, if yes. How was your fetch requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple dev forums has some good discussion on this.  A good post can be found [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/126167). General guideline from the post:  less than 16kb data blob ok, 100k ok as well, approaching 1MB and it is better to store outside of Core Data or any database.

In terms of fetching performance, it will boil down to how you have normalized your data model.